# How to run mvn command from gradle task?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a project with following structure:

[image]

**maven-as-submodule** - is just a gradle project;
**graph-gen** - is a maven-module inside a gradle project (not a submodule)

Well, my goal is to run command: `mvn graphwalker:generate-sources`
From a gradle task. So I've composed some:

```
task generateGraphBasedInterfaces(type: Exec) {
    workingDir './graph-gen'
    commandLine 'mvn graphwalker:generate-sources'
}
```

Everything seems okay, and I could run command `mvn graphwalker:generate-sources` without a problem from /graph-gen directory.

But when I'm trying to run it via gradle task - it ends up with error. So, here is some stacktrace:

> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':generateGraphBasedInterfaces'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)
>         at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:185)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:374)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:361)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:354)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:340)
>         at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
>         at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
>         at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
>         at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem
>     occurred starting process 'command 'mvn graphwalker:generate-sources''
>         at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:241)
>         at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:218)
>         at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:372)
>         at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:87)
>         at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
>         ... 3 more Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'mvn
>     graphwalker:generate-sources'
>         at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
>         at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.startProcess(ExecHandleRunner.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:71)
>         ... 4 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn graphwalker:generate-sources" (in directory
>     "/Users/Sanchellios/WORK_DIR/experiments/maven-as-submodule/graph-gen"):
>     error=2, No such file or directory
>         at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
>         ... 7 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
>         ... 8 more

I have even tried to generate maven wrapper inside of the **graph-gen** module - it didn't help.

Changing task to

task runMvnInterfaceGenerator(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn 'copyGraphsToGenerator'
    workingDir './graph-gen'
    args 'graphwalker:generate-sources'
    executable 'mvn'
}

worked well. So, what's problem with `commandLine`?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/dkorotych/gradle-maven-exec-plugin) Gradle plugin?

Comment: No, but i've changed task
task runMvnInterfaceGenerator(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn 'copyGraphsToGenerator'
    workingDir './graph-gen'
    args 'graphwalker:generate-sources'
    executable 'mvn'
}

and it works now. The question is, why  commandLine didn't work well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `commandLine` arguments need to be passed individually:

```
task generateGraphBasedInterfaces(type: Exec) {
    workingDir rootProject.getProjectDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/graph-gen"
    commandLine "mvn", "graphwalker:generate-sources"
}
```

Also make sure to have `mvn` / `mvn.cmd` on [`$PATH`](http://maven.apache.org/install.html).

Comment: I have the same issue. I have mvn on $PATH. If I run mvn -v on command line, it gives me the version of maven I have installed. However when I try to run the gradle task, it gives me the following error:

Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "C:\Users\abc\demo"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified. Any thoughts?

Comment: When it cannot find `mvn.cmd`, it is probably not on `$PATH`. Windows has system & user `$PATH`.